# how can i create a custom component that can give v-model attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I created a vue component (input) that can change direction depending on first character. Look like this:

```js
let smart_input = Vue.component('smart-input', {
    template: `<input :dir="direction" v-model="text">`,

    data() {
        return {
            text: ''
        }
    },

    computed: {
        direction(){
            let firstChar = this.text[0]
            return firstChar === undefined || firstChar.match(/[A-Za-z]/) !== null ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'
        }
    }
})
```

I added this component to my root Vue app.

So i want to add some attributes to my custom component (like v-model), but it don't work!

Look like this:

```html
<smart-input v-model='infomation'></smart-input>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Use props : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: I know about props. But i dont know how to use it in this problem.

Comment: [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) will help you. If still got any doubts let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this what you need but here is my take on v-model for a component

```
const smart_input = Vue.component('smart-input', {
    template: `
    <div>
    <input :dir="direction"  ref="inputref" :value="value" v-on:input="UpdateParent">  
      <button @click="Changeinfo">Parent Change</button>
    </div>
    `,
    props:{value:null},
    computed: {
        direction(){
            let firstChar = this.value[0];
            return firstChar === undefined || firstChar.match(/[A-Za-z]/) !== null ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'
        }
    },
    methods:{
    UpdateParent:function(event){
        this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    },
    Changeinfo:function(){
        this.$emit('input', 'changed')
    }
    }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components:{smart_input},
  data(){
    return{
        infomation:"test"
    }
  },
  methods:{
        TestVmodel:function(){
        this.infomation = "parent";
    }
  }  
})
```

This offers two-way binding like v-model

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/407158/